# Discord.Js The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: discord.js

I was coding a new command on discord which its focusing on OsuApi and now what I did is making a data function that writes the info on the Api.

I tried this code and it seems that I cannot fix it because I'm kinda new to this function and its bugging me  [image: heres the error]

and here's my code

```
const { member, channel, content, guild } = message
        const cache = {}

        let data = cache[member.id]

        if (!data) {
            const e1 = new ME()
                .setTitle(`Fetching Data Please Wait`)
                .setColor("Random")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
            console.log("Fecting From DataBase")
            const msg = await channel.send({ embeds: [e1] })

            await shi().then(async mongodb => {
                try {
                    const result = await us.findOne({ _id: member.id })

                    if (!result) {
                        const e2 = new ME()
                            .setTitle("Aweeee~")
                            .setColor(config.colors.no)
                            .setDescription("No user found set user using 's!setuser <username or userid>' ")
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
                        await setTimeout(() => {
                            msg.edit({ embeds: [e2] })
                        }, 5000);
                        return
                    }

                    cache[member.id] = data = [result.text]

                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    message.channel.send("Something bad happened sorry")
                }
            })

            api.user
                .get(data)
                .then(data => {

                    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data)
                    fs.writeFileSync('user.json', dataJSON)
                    const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('user.json')
                    const stringJSON = dataBuffer.toString()
                    const parseDATA = JSON.parse(stringJSON)

                    console.log(parseDATA.username)
                    channel.send("testing")

                })
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `data`? Because the error says it's `undefined`

Comment: Ive checked the value of data and it seems that the data function is an object